# Assembly data section

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, att

This question appeared in my exam:

> Given the following assembly code in at&t syntax (x86-64), what's the
> value of %rsp after the last line:
>
> ```
> .data
> var_1: .int 0
> var_2: .int -1
> var_3: .quad var_2
>
> .text
> .global main
> main:
>     mov var_3, %rbx # rbx = var_3
>     lea 6(%rbx), %rsp # rsp = 6 + var_3
>     pushq $0xffc8 # rsp = 6 + var_3 - 8 = var_3 - 2
> ```

My professor told me that my solution (appears in notes) is wrong and the correct answer is `%rsp = var_2 - 2`.
Can someone kindly explain why is that?

Comment: `mov var_3, %rbx` loads the contents of `var_3` into `%rbx`.  To load the address, you would have to use `mov $var_3, %rbx`.

Comment: You're supposed to assume that the push doesn't fault?  That would potentially set RSP to the kernel stack pointer from the TSS.  Also, the comment on the first instruction is wrong: `mov var_3, %rbx` loads the address of `var_2` because that's what's stored in that `.quad`.  nvm, fuz pointed that out.

Comment: @fuz and the contents of var_3 is the address of var_2 or -1?

Comment: @Daniel As the code says, at label `var_3`, the address of `var_2` is stored.