# `mov` Command In Assembly

Tags: assembly, memory, 64-bit, x86-64, att

I wrote the following assembly code (at&t syntax, x86-64):

```
.data
var_1: .int 0x00005040
var_2: .byte 0x20
var_3: .int 0x0102ffee

.text
.global main
main:
    movq (var_1), %r9
```

According to the answers I got on my previous question: [Assembly data section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68587151/assembly-data-section?noredirect=1#comment121212320_68587151) `movq var_1, %r9` will load the value of `var_1` inside `%r9`.

But since we have `(var_1)` we will load the address of `var_1` inside `%r9`.

But running the above code I can always see the following value stored in `%r9`: **0x02ffee2000005040**

Please help me understand why.

Memory layout from lower to higher addresses (Working with little endian):

```
40
50
00
00
20
ee
ff
02
01
```

Comment: _"But since we have (var_1) we will load the address of var_1 inside %r9."_ What made you think that? I don't deal with AT&T syntax much, but I thought you'd use `$var_1` to get the address.

Comment: @Michael: That's correct, this is identical to `movq var_1, %r9`, as we can confirm by assembling and disassembling.  So it's loading the 8-byte window that overlaps the .int, .byte, and .int.

Comment: Parentheses around a symbol in an operand are just for grouping.  They do not change the meaning of the operand.  They only make a difference around register names, indicating that the addressing mode is indirect.

Comment: @Michael () in assembly means read from memory

Comment: @fuz even with that how can I reach the correct answer (shown in bold)

Comment: _"() in assembly means read from memory"_. Not really. Like @fuz mentioned, they do matter in the case of registers (i.e. `(%rax)` vs just `%rax`) to separate between a memory operand and an ordinary register operand. But even then, you could be using it with `lea`, which wouldn't read from memory. Also, _"() in assembly means read from memory"_ appears to contradict what you said in your question about _"(var_1) will load the address of var_1"_. Just read Peter's and fuz' comments.

Comment: @Daniel You do a quad word (8 byte) load from `var_1`.  These 8 bytes are the 4 bytes of `.int 0x00005040`, the 1 byte of `.byte 0x20` and then the first 3 bytes of `.int 0x0102ffee`.  In fact, these are exactly the first 8 of the bytes you list in your “memory layout” section of the question.  Consider using `objdump` to investigate what the data looks like in memory in case you need a visualisation.